# При каких условиях уничтожается Task?

Tags: c#, task, сборщик-мусора

Абстрактный пример: есть `_reader`, который асинхронно читает данные. Есть `cancellationToken`, который станет `Cancel`, когда приложение должно завершить свою работу:

```
while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    var readingTask = _reader.ReadAsync();
    await Task.WhenAny(readingTask, Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, cancellationToken));
    
    if (readingTask.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
    {
        var readResult = readingTask.Result;
        // Обрабатываем readResult
    }
}
```

Предположим, что цикл выполнился раз 40. Будет ли засоряться память либо проседать производительность из-за того, что каждую итерацию цикла создается задача `Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, cancellationToken)`, которая завершится только в случае, когда токен будет `Cancel`? Либо сборщик мусора (либо кто-то еще) будет уничтожать эти бесконечные задачи?

Comment: Не будет GC собирать таску, пока она не отработает. Представьте, у вас запущен код, выполняются вычисления, пусть даже вы их не ожидаете и ссылку на запущеную таску не храните, а тут приходит Сборщик и убивает рабочий поток только потому что основной поток не помнит про таск. Как-то не логично было бы. Потому как только `WhenAny` отработал, надо канселить токен, привязанный к `Delay`, создайте отдельный CTS для этого, [даже с привязкой к основному токену отмены](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.createlinkedtokensource?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как и любой объект, Task уничтожается когда на него не остаётся ссылок. Обычно ссылок на него - две:

1. от потребителя объекта (того, кто ждёт);
2. от того, кто выполняет работу.

Первую ссылку удерживаете вы сами (для временных объектов её "держит" только оператор await). А вот вторая ссылка живёт пока задача не окажется завершена либо отменена.

Соответственно, обычно для уничтожения Task необходимо и достаточно забыть про него потребителю и отменить работу. Но в каждом индивидуальном случае могут быть свои особенности.

---

Теперь о `Task.Delay`. Ссылка на `Task.Delay` удерживается активным таймером, и пропадает при отмене таймера. Таким образом, вам достаточно отменить таймер чтобы объект был собран GC:

```cs
using (var tempCts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedSource(cancellationToken)) {
    await Task.WhenAny(readingTask, Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, tempCts.Token));
    tempCts.Cancel(); // отменяет таймер и даёт собрать задачу
}
```

Однако, судя по `Timeout.Infinite`, я вижу что эта задача является "вечной". Тут можно обойтись вовсе без `Task.Delay`:

```cs
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
using (cancellationToken.Register(tcs.SetCanceled))
     await Task.WhenAny(readingTask, tcs.Task);
```

Отмечу, что using тут обязателен, иначе ссылка на tcs будет удерживаться токеном отмены.

---

PS третий способ сделать то, что вы добиваетесь - вот такой:

```cs
await readingTask.ContinueWith(_ => {}, cancellationToken);
```

Здесь `ContinueWith` тоже создаёт временную задачу, ссылка на которую удерживается пока она не будет завершена или отменена (однако, в отличии от варианта с `Task.Delay`, она завершается сразу после завершения `readingTask`).

Comment: C `TaskCompletionSource` красиво получилось!) А в третьем случае `await readingTask.ContinueWith(_ => {}, cancellationToken);` ведь не завершится, если `cancellationToken == Cancel` и `readingTask` еще не завершился?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko не понимаю что вы имеете в виду

Answer (score 2):

Я потестировал вырожденный случай - вообще без `cancellationToken`, тут это по-моему не важно. Результат - память таки кончается, не смотря на работу сборщика мусора.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static async void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Begin...");
        Console.WriteLine("Memory used {0:N0}", GC.GetTotalMemory(false));
        for(var i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            await Task.WhenAny(Task.CompletedTask, Task.Delay(100000));
            if(i % 10000 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Collecting");
                GC.Collect();
                GC.Collect();
                Console.WriteLine("Memory used {0:N0}", GC.GetTotalMemory(true));
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
Begin...
Memory used 8,159,128
Collecting
Memory used 7,964,504
Collecting
Memory used 27,284,692
Fatal Error: Memory usage limit was exceeded
```

[Ссылка](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xjWEC6), по которой можно проверить работу кода.

Comment: Действительно. Что-то я сам не подумал это проверить :) Можно оптимизировать и вынести `Task.Delay(100000)` в отдельную переменную за цикл, тогда код завершится успешно.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko В смысле, чтобы это был один таск, а не каждый раз новый? Тогда да, по идее всё будет ок :)  А так видимо ссылки на таски есть у какого-то объекта глобальной видимости, поэтому создаваемые таски продолжают жить и при выходе из своей области видимости